# Cannot insert to a new column added after scaffolding in cake PHP

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cake PHP. I was working on existing website on cakePHP. Due to some requirements of client I had to add a new column in one of the table in database. I can make entry to all of the field except the one which I recently created. I guess the problem is because that was not present during scaffolding. But I am not aware how to solve this issue.

I am able to access that field while fetching from database by simply adding `array('fields'=>'*'`) in `$this->Model_name->find('first',array('fields'=>'*'))`.

I tried this for making new insert `$this->request->data['ModelName']['field_name'] = 'value';`
before using save function. But the problem is all the fields gets insert except for this new field that I added.

I hope the thing is clear.

Comment: You do realize that I pointed out pretty clearly in my answer that you should CLEAR THE CACHE!!! You just responded with "If you can see my question above, you can find that I already did that" and one hour later you relize you didnt? And marked someone else's answer (which was an exact duplicate of mine 1 hour later) as correct? that's not the way to go my friend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case remind me about 2 of my mistake that make I cannot save my new field.

1 make sure you have new field in your database table.
2 in my productin system I was set debug to 0 so model and persisten cache doesn't update.

To clear model and persistent cache you can set `Configure::write('debug', 2);` in `app/Config/Core.php` or manual delete cache in command line.

```
rm -f app/tmp/cache/models/cake_model_*  
rm -f app/tmp/cache/persistent/cake_core_*
```

Comment: you kinda just repeated me here :)

Comment: Configure::write('debug',2); this worked for me... had me scratching my head for a little bit...

Answer (score 2):

Please read the documentation - 
ModelName is CamelCased:

```
$this->request->data['ModelName']['field_name'] = 'value';
```

If only this new field does not get added it is very likely that you did not clear the (peristent/model) cache. You need to do that for cake to recognize the newly added db fields.

Comment: If you can see my question above, you can find that I already did that.

Comment: I mean I am sorry... Just to let you know.  There are no underscores in model name.. The model name is completely ok. THis is the exact line: this->request->data['User']['is_business'] = $_POST['busi'];

Comment: Never use post - use `$this->request->data`. Why is it in "busi" and not - as in cake usually the case - in `$this->request->data['User']['busi']` or if not posted via FormHelper in `$this->request->data['busi']`?

Comment: Don't worry about that, I am getting the posted value. I just added a pair of radio buttons. I had tried the way you told. just assume that I am doing $this->request->data['User']['is_business'] = 1; and the field type is int.

Comment: Then it must work if you have the field in your db and you double checked that the cache is cleared.

Comment: Please let us know if this field is present in database

Comment: Check what is the engine (Memcache, File,..) configured as the cache handling engine in the Config/core.php. If it is not 'File', then there will not be file in the temp folder to delete.